# Finding second derivative for $(a\times tb)\times (a+t^2b)$

Tags: calculus, vectors

How would one find the second derivative of

$f(t)=(a \times tb)\times(a+t^2b)$

where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

I did the following

$f(t)=(a \times tb)\times(2tb)+(b)\times(a+t^2b)$

then taking the cross product I get

$f'(t)=(a\times 2bt)+(a\times b)$

But would this be right.

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be cross product, and a and b to be vectors?

Comment: yes that is what I mean the bold is not working

Comment: If you denote $X$ by the cross product and $a, b$ to be vectors, then we write $a \times b$.  Otherwise, let me know

Answer (score 0):

$(AxBt)x(2Bt)+(AxB)+(Bt)x(A+Bt^2)$